# c++ Delete inherited member variable in child class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
Struct Base 
{
   int x;
   double y;    
}

Struct A : public Base
{   
}

Struct B : public Base
{  //here I don't want x (Base::x) to be inherited.
   // is there a way to delete it (something like delete Base::x)
}

Struct C : public Base
{   
}
```

What is considered best practice to achieve such a task? `x` should be inherited by `A` and `C`, (and maybe by many other classes) so I can't put it in the private section of `Base`. The only way I see is to remove `x` from `Base` and put it in `A` & `C`. But there should be another way right? Thanks.

Comment: If `B` shouldn't have `Base::x`, then `B` shouldn't inherit publicly from `Base`.

Comment: Why is `B` a `Base` if it doesn't want a `x`? Perhaps you have a "`BaseX`" and "`BaseY`" concept struggling to happen. Or perhaps they should be contained, when needed, not inherited?

Comment: BTW: why the downvotes?

Comment: @doctorlove consider a base class `RestaurantBase` which has among other member a member `m_teaspoon`. Every restaurant classes (`Struct ItaliaFood {}`, `Struct FrenchFood {}`, etc) inherit from `RestaurantBase`. Now there is some Japanese restaurant (`Struct JapanFood {}`), which is also a restaurant but doesn't have any teaspoon. So for it I don't want`m_teaspoon` to be inherited. But it is a restaurant and should inherit the 100 others members of `RestaurantBase`

Comment: @Gaetan Read Scott Meyors effective c++ - Item 34. Differentiate between inheritance of interface and inheritance of implementation. By having teaspoon as part of your interface you are forcing this implementation detail on the children of your base class. Consider making utensils and abstract part of the interface.

Comment: If restaurants have teaspoons then something without a teaspoon is not a restaurant. A different way of carving things up will avoid the problem. as @FantasticMrFox says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to "delete" inherited data members, and you cannot even hide them. They get intrinsic part of the subclass. 
If `B` shall inherit just parts of `Base`, you need to split `Base`:

```
Struct Base 
{
   double y;    
}

Struct BaseWithX : public Base
{
   int x;
}

Struct A : public BaseWithX
{ }

Struct B : public Base
{ }

Struct C : public BaseWithX
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, maybe c++18 should introduce such a `delete x`, to allow partial inheritance. If you consider the restaurant example I've mentioned above, it is quite annoying to create a new base class just to prevent inheritance of a single member variable

Comment: @Gaetan Trouble is, your described use case does not really abide by the principles of OOP, so it's not likely to be a use case that the language caters for in its implementation of inheritance. You're basically falling into [the circle-ellipse trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem), but a little worse: there is no reason for "food" to be a kind of "restaurant".

Answer (score 3):

Public inheritance makes an `is-a` relationship. That means `B` **is a** `Base`. And that means if `Base` has `x` then since `B` **is a** `Base`, `B` will have `x`. You need to re-think this design if you have that problem. Consider switching the relationship between `B` and `Base` to composition:

```
struct B {
    void some_function_using_base();
private:
    Base base_;
};
```

Comment: consider a base class `RestaurantBase` which has among other member a member `m_teaspoon`. Every restaurant classes (`Struct ItaliaFood {}`, `Struct FrenchFood {}`, etc) inherit from `RestaurantBase`. Now there is some Japanese restaurant (`Struct JapanFood {}`), which is also a restaurant but doesn't have any teaspoon. So for it I don't want `m_teaspoon` to be inherited. But it is a restaurant and should inherit the 100 others members of `RestaurantBase`

Comment: @Gaetan Read Scott Meyors effective c++ - Item 34. Differentiate between inheritance of interface and inheritance of implementation. By having teaspoon as part of your interface you are forcing this implementation detail on the children of your base class. Consider making `utensils` and abstract part of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of hiding a member of the base class, you can achieve that by inheriting privately from it and selectively exposing public (or protected) base class members using `using`:

```
Struct Base 
{
   int x;
   double y;    
}

Struct A : public Base
{   
}

Struct B : private Base
{  
   using Base::x; // only pull in x in the public section of the class
}

...

B b;
double y = b.y // <= compilation error here
```